# Type parameter with multiple bounds

Tags: java, generics

This code compiles:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Arrays;
class Test<T extends Arrays & Serializable> { }
```

but if I replace the last line with

```
class Test<T extends Serializable & Arrays> { }
```

I get "interface expected here". Why?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [section 4.4 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4):

> Every type variable declared as a type parameter has a bound. If no bound is declared for a type variable, Object is assumed. If a bound is declared, it consists of either:
>
> - a single type variable T, or
> - a class or interface type T possibly followed by interface types I1 & ... & In.
>
> It is a compile-time error if any of the types I1 ... In is a class type or type variable.

So basically, if your bounds include a class, it has to be the *first* bound.

(Given that `Arrays` can't be instantiated, it's unclear why you would *want* a bound including it, mind you... was this just an example?)

Comment: «was this just an example?» Yes it was :-) I was just experimenting with bounded type parameters. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If one of the bounds is a class, it must be specified first.