# Enum and generics "interface expected" with multiple bounds

Tags: java

I'd like to be able to map enums to "alternative values", since in our legacy database some enums are using values that are not mappable to enums (ie, not starting with 0 when int, and not being expressable as enum name when String type).

The following works fine to be able to map enums to an alternative name:

```
public class EnumAlternativeNameHelper {

  private static <T extends Enum<T> & EnumAlternativeName> T safeGetByAlternativeName(Class<T> enumClass, String alternativeName) {
    for ( T t : EnumSet.allOf(enumClass) ) {
      if ( t.getAlternativeName().equals(alternativeName) ) {
        return t;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }


  public static <T extends Enum<T> & EnumAlternativeName> Optional<T> getIfPresent(Class<T> enumClass, String alternativeName) {
    T t = safeGetByAlternativeName(enumClass,alternativeName);
    return Optional.fromNullable(t);
  }


  public static <T extends Enum<T> & EnumAlternativeName> T valueOf(Class<T> enumClass, String alternativeName) {
    T t = safeGetByAlternativeName(enumClass,alternativeName);
    return checkNotNull(t,"No alternative name of " + enumClass + " correspond to the provided alternative name = [" + alternativeName+"]");
  }


  public static <T extends Enum<T> & EnumAlternativeName> Optional<T> valueOfNullSafe(Class<T> enumClass, String alternativeName) {
    if ( alternativeName == null) {
      return Optional.absent();
    }
    return Optional.of( valueOf(enumClass,alternativeName) );
  }

}
```

As I now need to handle an alternative ordinal mapping, I've written something like this:

```
public class EnumAlternativeValueHelper<EnumMappingInterface,ValueType> {

  private final Function<EnumMappingInterface,ValueType> mappingFunction;

  public EnumAlternativeValueHelper(Function<EnumMappingInterface, ValueType> mappingFunction) {
    Preconditions.checkArgument(mappingFunction != null);
    this.mappingFunction = mappingFunction;
  }


  private <EnumType extends Enum<EnumType> & EnumMappingInterface> EnumType safeGetByAlternativeValue(Class<EnumType> enumClass, ValueType value) {
    for ( EnumType enumInstance : EnumSet.allOf(enumClass) ) {
      if ( mappingFunction.apply(enumInstance).equals(value) ) {
        return enumInstance;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

}
```

But the generics declaration `<EnumType extends Enum<EnumType> & EnumMappingInterface>` does compile because of EnumMappingInterface: "interface expected here".

I have seen this answer:
[Type parameter with multiple bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975690/type-parameter-with-multiple-bounds)

Actually, my EnumMappingInterface is a generic type which will represent an interface. It will be either EnumAlternativeName or EnumAlternativeOrdinal which both define a method returning the alternative value.

Is there any solution so that I can achieve what I am trying to do? Thanks

**Edit:**

EnumMappingInterface is a generic type so it doesn't have any defition but I am supposed to pass this interface as the generic type:

```
public interface EnumAlternativeName {

  String getAlternativeName();

  Function<EnumAlternativeName,String> GET_ALTERNATIVE_NAME = new Function<EnumAlternativeName,String>() {
    @Override
    public String apply(EnumAlternativeName input) {
      return input.getAlternativeName();
    }
  };

}
```

Comment: can you please show your `EnumMappingInterface` definition?

Comment: It doesn't have any definition because it is a generic type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it works fine for overriding enum name() and ordinal() by defining a single interface which abstract both cases:

```
public interface EnumAlternativeValue<ValueType> {
  ValueType getAlternativeValue();
}
```

Then I can do:

```
public class EnumAlternativeValueHelper {


  private static <ValueType,EnumType extends Enum<EnumType> & EnumAlternativeValue<ValueType>> EnumType safeGetByAlternativeValue(Class<EnumType> enumClass, ValueType value) {
    for ( EnumType enumInstance : EnumSet.allOf(enumClass) ) {
      if ( enumInstance.getAlternativeValue().equals(value) ) {
        return enumInstance;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }


  public static <ValueType,EnumType extends Enum<EnumType> & EnumAlternativeValue<ValueType>> Optional<EnumType> getIfPresent(Class<EnumType> enumClass, ValueType value) {
    EnumType t = safeGetByAlternativeValue(enumClass,value);
    return Optional.fromNullable(t);
  }


  public static <ValueType,EnumType extends Enum<EnumType> & EnumAlternativeValue<ValueType>> EnumType valueOf(Class<EnumType> enumClass, ValueType value) {
    EnumType t = safeGetByAlternativeValue(enumClass,value);
    return checkNotNull(t,"No alternative value of " + enumClass + " correspond to the provided alternative value = [" + value+"]");
  }


  public static <ValueType,EnumType extends Enum<EnumType> & EnumAlternativeValue<ValueType>> Optional<EnumType> valueOfNullSafe(Class<EnumType> enumClass, ValueType value) {
    if ( value == null) {
      return Optional.absent();
    }
    return Optional.of( valueOf(enumClass,value) );
  }

  public static <ValueType> Function<EnumAlternativeValue<ValueType>,ValueType> getAlternativeValueFunction() {
    return new Function<EnumAlternativeValue<ValueType>,ValueType>() {
      @Override
      public ValueType apply(EnumAlternativeValue<ValueType> input) {
        return input.getAlternativeValue();
      }
    };
  }

}
```

And the test:

```
public class EnumAlternativeValueHelperTest {


  private enum EnumUnderTest implements EnumAlternativeValue<String> {
    VALUE1("AlternativeName1"),
    VALUE2("AlternativeName2"),
    ;
    private final String alternativeName;
    private EnumUnderTest(String alternativeName) {
      this.alternativeName = alternativeName;
    }
    @Override
    public String getAlternativeValue() {
      return alternativeName;
    }
  }

  private enum EnumUnderTest2 implements EnumAlternativeValue<Integer> {
    VALUE1(1),
    VALUE2(2),
    ;
    private final int alternativeOrdinal;
    private EnumUnderTest2(int alternativeOrdinal) {
      this.alternativeOrdinal = alternativeOrdinal;
    }
    @Override
    public Integer getAlternativeValue() {
      return alternativeOrdinal;
    }
  }



  @Test
  public void getIfPresentReturnsValueTest() {
    assertThat( EnumAlternativeValueHelper.getIfPresent(EnumUnderTest.class,"AlternativeName1") )
            .isEqualTo(Optional.of(EnumUnderTest.VALUE1));
    assertThat( EnumAlternativeValueHelper.getIfPresent(EnumUnderTest2.class,1) )
            .isEqualTo(Optional.of(EnumUnderTest2.VALUE1));
  }
  @Test
  public void getIfPresentReturnsAbsent1Test() {
    assertThat( EnumAlternativeValueHelper.getIfPresent(EnumUnderTest.class,"AlternativeNameUnknown") )
            .isEqualTo( Optional.<EnumUnderTest>absent() );
    assertThat( EnumAlternativeValueHelper.getIfPresent(EnumUnderTest2.class,0) )
            .isEqualTo( Optional.<EnumUnderTest2>absent() );
  }
  @Test
  public void getIfPresentReturnsAbsentWhenNonAlternativeValueIsProvidedTest() {
    assertThat( EnumAlternativeValueHelper.getIfPresent(EnumUnderTest.class, EnumUnderTest.VALUE1.name()) )
            .isEqualTo( Optional.<EnumUnderTest>absent() );
    assertThat( EnumAlternativeValueHelper.getIfPresent(EnumUnderTest2.class, EnumUnderTest2.VALUE1.ordinal()) )
            .isEqualTo( Optional.<EnumUnderTest2>absent() );
  }
  @Test
  public void getIfPresentWhenBadAlternativeValueReturnsAbsentTest() {
    assertThat( EnumAlternativeValueHelper.getIfPresent(EnumUnderTest.class,null) )
            .isEqualTo(Optional.<EnumUnderTest>absent());
    assertThat( EnumAlternativeValueHelper.getIfPresent(EnumUnderTest2.class,null) )
            .isEqualTo(Optional.<EnumUnderTest2>absent());
  }



  @Test
  public void valueOfReturnsValueTest() {
    assertThat( EnumAlternativeValueHelper.valueOf(EnumUnderTest.class, "AlternativeName1") )
            .isEqualTo( EnumUnderTest.VALUE1 );
    assertThat( EnumAlternativeValueHelper.valueOf(EnumUnderTest2.class, 1) )
            .isEqualTo( EnumUnderTest2.VALUE1 );
  }
  @Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
  public void valueOfThrowsExceptionTest() {
    EnumAlternativeValueHelper.valueOf(EnumUnderTest.class, "AlternativeNameUnknown");
    EnumAlternativeValueHelper.valueOf(EnumUnderTest2.class, 0);
  }
  @Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
  public void valueOfThrowsExceptionWhenBadAlternativeValueTest() {
    EnumAlternativeValueHelper.valueOf(EnumUnderTest.class, null);
    EnumAlternativeValueHelper.valueOf(EnumUnderTest2.class, null);
  }
  @Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
  public void valueOfThrowsExceptionWhenNonAlternativeValueIsProvidedTest() {
    EnumAlternativeValueHelper.valueOf(EnumUnderTest.class, EnumUnderTest.VALUE1.name());
    EnumAlternativeValueHelper.valueOf(EnumUnderTest2.class, EnumUnderTest.VALUE1.ordinal());
  }


  @Test
  public void nullSafeValueOfReturnsValueTest() {
    assertThat(EnumAlternativeValueHelper.valueOfNullSafe(EnumUnderTest.class, "AlternativeName1"))
            .isEqualTo(Optional.of(EnumUnderTest.VALUE1));
    assertThat(EnumAlternativeValueHelper.valueOfNullSafe(EnumUnderTest2.class, 1))
            .isEqualTo(Optional.of(EnumUnderTest2.VALUE1));
  }
  @Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
  public void nullSafeValueOfThrowsExceptionTest() {
    EnumAlternativeValueHelper.valueOfNullSafe(EnumUnderTest.class, "AlternativeNameUnknown");
    EnumAlternativeValueHelper.valueOfNullSafe(EnumUnderTest2.class, 1);
  }
  @Test
  public void nullSafeValueOfReturnsAbsentWhenBadAlternativeValueTest() {
    assertThat( EnumAlternativeValueHelper.valueOfNullSafe(EnumUnderTest.class, null) )
            .isEqualTo(Optional.<EnumUnderTest>absent());
    assertThat( EnumAlternativeValueHelper.valueOfNullSafe(EnumUnderTest2.class, null) )
            .isEqualTo(Optional.<EnumUnderTest2>absent());
  }
  @Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
  public void nullSafeValueOfThrowsExceptionWhenNonAlternativeValueIsProvidedTest() {
    EnumAlternativeValueHelper.valueOf(EnumUnderTest.class, EnumUnderTest.VALUE1.name());
    EnumAlternativeValueHelper.valueOf(EnumUnderTest2.class, EnumUnderTest.VALUE1.ordinal());
  }



  @Test
  public void alternativeValueFunctionTest() {
    assertThat(EnumAlternativeValueHelper.<String>getAlternativeValueFunction().apply(EnumUnderTest.VALUE1)).isEqualTo("AlternativeName1");
    assertThat(EnumAlternativeValueHelper.<Integer>getAlternativeValueFunction().apply(EnumUnderTest2.VALUE1)).isEqualTo(1);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you specify bounds for generic type you can use only classes and interfaces. You can't bound your generic type with another generic type. In your case I suggest you to introduce third marker interface EnumMappingInterface:

```
public interface EnumMappingInterface {
}
```

And use it as a parent interface for EnumAlternativeName and EnumAlternativeOrdinal interaces:

```
public interface EnumAlternativeName extends EnumMappingInterface {
    ...
}
```

In this case you a eligible to use `EnumMappingInterface` as a second bound for your `EnumType` generic type.

Comment: yes but then please explain how do I create 2 instances of EnumAlternativeValueHelper (one for alternative name and one for alternative ordinal) and how do I use them since I can pass as argument an enum which may not be mappable with the value I provide. I'm looking for a typesafe solution

Comment: one solution i can think of is to put all common methods to `EnumMappingInterface` and use them directly in your helper

Comment: Then it means duplicating methods for String VS Integer result, extactly like duplicating the EnumAlternativeNameHelper (like shawn in my post) and creating EnumAlternativeOrdinalHelper: the code is not factorized